# i can't find source control key in windows registry

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i installed visual studio 2010 ultimate version and tfs2010 when i wana creating custom checkin policy i can't find source control in windows registry to add string key and assigned dll file to that.
registry path is:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation
please help me
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right location is:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
```

See [this post](http://blogs.teamfoundation.co.za/2011/04/custom-check-in-policies-for-tfs-2010.html) for more information about Check-in policies and TFS/VS 2010

Comment: beacuse i install windows7 X64